# In Pandas dataframe, I want to get only a part of the column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

In Pandas Dataframe, I want to get only a part of the column and remove the rest and use it as a data cleaning technique.

- under Messages column the following are the list of items, I just want the A part in order to train my model

```
ColumnB
{'A': 'At Paris residency.. :grin:', 'B': 'hop-general', 'C': '2020-03-21 05:26:48'} 
{'A': 'At Delhi residency.. :worried:', 'B': 'hop-general', 'C': '2020-03-21 07:29:28'}
```

What can I do to only select the content in A?

Need to clean the data using Pandas

Comment: `df['ColumnB'].str['A']`